# If don't know what has done before, how to restore to the default status?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

A canvas,has do something already,like scale, translated, and rotate, but i don't know whether it changed, and it don't saved before, so i can't use the restore() method to restore.

And i will draw something now, but if the canvas.context has translated (or others), my operation will go to wrong position.

```
// no save
ctx.translate(300,100);
ctx.scale(1,0.5);
ctx.rotate(Math.PI/2);
...
// to do something
...
// at now , how i go back the default?
```

so i want to know how can i go back the default status and todo my action correctly? The simpler the better, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the transformation matrix back the identity matrix:

```
ctx.setTransform(1, 0,
                 0, 1,
                 0, 0);
```

Comment: never knew about this useful snippet. +1